# Why does Javasript's strict comparison act the way it does?

Tags: javascript, comparison, operators, strict

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

If the main difference between Javascript's "strict comparison" operators and the traditional ones is type coercion, why does

```
0.1+0.2===0.3;
```

return false?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox and Chrome, `0.1 + 0.2` is `0.30000000000000004`, which is not equal to `0.3`. This is presumably caused by it not being possible to represent `0.1` exactly as a floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

because 0.1 is tricky
it's <strike>irrational</strike> recurring in binary (see comments)

EDIT
actually I'm winging it here, I don't know that for sure. Is there a Math.boffin out there who can disprove or provide a proof?
would be very interesting

Comment: "Irrational" isn't true - 1 / 10 is a rational number regardless of what base you're storing things in. However, it *is* a recurring binary, so it's not possible to represent it exactly using a normal floating-point representation.

Comment: 0.1 in decimal is 0.00011001100110011... recurring in binary.

Comment: rational being representable as a fraction - silly me. Could you shed some light on why it is recurring?

Comment: in binary, each digit past the dot represents 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, just as in decimal it is 1/10, 1/100, 1/1000. Using just these binary fractions, you can't ever add up to 1/10 exactly. The closest you can get is 1/16 + 1/32 + 1/256 + 1/512 + .... (0.0001100110011...)

Comment: IEEE standards (754) dictate fractional numbers be stored this way.